# sql query for using arraylist

Tags: sql, oracle

I have an `arraylist of Strings` and a `string which is the csv format of this list`.
I want to write an sql query which refines the result on this list basis.
So, I want something like ---

```
select * from table_name where name in (`ArrayList<String> values` or `csv format string`).
```

I believe that something like `procedure`, `functions` etc. can be made to solve the purpose.
I just want to know how can i achieve this.
Thanks

Comment: not able to understand. Explain properly

Comment: Iteration!! thats it with String ArrayList. If this is Integer ArrayList then list.toString() can help you.

Comment: I am not asking what you are telling dear. please read the question again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's unclear what exactly you mean by ArrayList; are you talking about a C#/Java/whatever type here (since Oracle PL/SQL doesn't have Generics)?

Anyway, here is one way to convert a comma-separated list in PL/SQL into a PL/SQL table und use it for an IN search:

(see [AskTom](http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0%3a%3a%3a%3aP11_QUESTION_ID:210612357425))

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE STRINGLISTT as table of varchar2(4000);

create or replace function in_list(p_string    in varchar2,
                       p_delimiter in varchar2) return StringListT is
        l_string long default p_string || p_delimiter;
        l_data   StringListT := StringListT();
        n        number;
      begin
        loop
          exit when l_string is null;
          n := instr(l_string,
                     p_delimiter);
          l_data.extend;
          l_data(l_data.count) := ltrim(rtrim(substr(l_string,
                                                     1,
                                                     n - 1)));
          l_string := substr(l_string,
                             n + 1);
        end loop;      
        return l_data;      
      end;
```

Usage:

```
  select * from my_tab t where t.name in 
   (select * from table(in_list('A,B', ',')));
```

Comment: +1, Yes dear I got it working .. thanks a lot. But for my knowledge, I would like to understand the 'TYPE' part.  
Can u please elaborate it.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you right, then you can try:

```
declare
  v_al  arrayList := new arrayList('11', '22', '33');
  v_csv varchar2(32767) := '111,222,333,444';

  i number;
begin

  select count(*)
    into i
    from table_name
   where val in (select column_value from table(v_al))
      or val in (select distinct regexp_substr(v_csv, '[^,]+', 1, level) token
                   from dual
                 connect by level <= regexp_count(v_csv, ',') + 1);

  dbms_output.put_line(i);

end;
```

in this example I used `count(*)` but it is not necessary (can also be in a cursor or as a sql query)

[Here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/1be5c/1) is a fiddle (using only sql)